# Beautifulsoup Python loops

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I have this code that returns `None` for each row, can someone help me?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

website = 'https://www.bloodyelbow.com/22198483/comprehensive-list-of-ufc-fighters-who-have-tested-positive-for-covid-19'

response = requests.get(website)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find('table',{'class':'p-data-table'}).find('tbody').find_all('tr')

name=[]
reported_date=[]
card=[]
card_date=[]
opponent=[]
resolution=[]

for result in results:
    print(name.append(i.find_all('td')[0].get_text()))
```

Comment: What is `i` in `i.find_all('td')[0].get_text()`? What's the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` directly and get all the columns up to the last two:

```
import pandas


website = "https://www.bloodyelbow.com/22198483/comprehensive-list-of-ufc-fighters-who-have-tested-positive-for-covid-19"

df = pandas.read_html(website)[0].iloc[:, :-2]
print(df.to_string())
```

Output (truncated):

```
                  Fighter      Reported                Card   Card Date              Opponent                                                                                                                Resolution
0              Rani Yahya     7/31/2021        UFC Vegas 33   7/31/2021         Kyung Ho Kang                                                                                                           Fight scratched
1            Amanda Nunes     7/29/2021             UFC 265    8/7/2021         Julianna Pena                                                                                                           Fight scratched
2            Amanda Ribas     5/23/2021        UFC Vegas 28    6/5/2021           Angela Hill                                                                                                           Fight scratched
3         Jack Hermansson     5/19/2021             UFC 262   5/17/2021      Edmen Shahbazyan                                                                                     Rescheduled for UFC Vegas 27 - May 22
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, it is one way, really simple and usefull, however only works with tables. thanks